# How to replace the url within an css file with gulp?

Tags: javascript, css, regex, gulp

Hello everyone i have to replace within a css file all urls with gulp. For example url(picture.webp) to $CMS_REF(media:"picture")$. This should work for all urls with the specific path. How can i do this?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the module [gulp-string-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-string-replace) which can use regex, strings or even functions.

> My Regex isn't that great, so forgive any mistakes please.

**Examples:**

1.**Regex:**

```
var replace = require('gulp-string-replace');

gulp.task('replace', function() {
  gulp.src(["./css/index.css"]) //Specify allowed files  
    .pipe(replace(new RegExp('@url@', 'g'), '$CMS_REF(media:"picture")$'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/index.css'))
});
```

2.**String:**

```
var replace = require('gulp-string-replace');
gulp.task('replace', function() {
  gulp.src(["./css/index.css"]) //Specify allowed files 
     .pipe(replace('url(picture.webp)', '$CMS_REF(media:"picture")$'))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/index.css'))
});
```

3.**Function:**

```
var replace = require('gulp-string-replace');
gulp.task('replace', function() {
  gulp.src(["./css/index.css"]) //Specify allowed files 
    .pipe(replace('url(picture.webp)', function () {
       return '$CMS_REF(media:"picture")$';
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/index.css'))
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But it have to be global. I have to get the content between every url in my css file und replace it corresponding to that.

Comment: I guess you can use RegEx Replace for that. 
Something like this:

`gulp.task('replace', function() {
  gulp.src(["./css/index.css"])
    .pipe(replace(url({1}),'$CMS_REF(media:"picture")$'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/index.css'))
});`

Comment: Sorry but this also dont helps me, because you have in your $CMS_REF "picture" written. The string have to come from the specific url.